# fitting probability distributions to observed data c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, statistics, probability-density

Actually, I have a vector of real numbers (for example 1*300). I am looking for a snippet of code in c++ for fitting a probability distribution function to this vector.

Afterward, I want to use this pdf for calculating the probability of any entry of this vector.
It is possible to create a histogram for this vector (which looks to be an easier solution), but I need to do quantization for that which I don't like that.

Even more, I have another vector of real numbers with the same size. I would like to fit a 2D joint probability for these two vectors. The result will be used similarly for calculating the probability of any joint entry of two vectors.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Did you really mean to tag this [tag:pdf]??? Also guessing what you have from prose doesn't make your question very clear.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ probability density function... I have retagged though since SO pdf is related to documents

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 Most probable, of course. But that tag doesn't fit, anyway!

Comment: This isn't clear; what do you mean by "fit a probability distribution to this vector"?  Are you saying that each element of this vector is generated independently, and you want to estimate the PDF of the generating process?  If so, this is a hard problem.  You would need to have some candidate distributions to test against (e.g. Gaussian, exponential), then test each in turn to see which provides the best fit.  If this is indeed the problem, then you should ask at http://stats.stackexchange.com first, as this is a stats problem, not a programming problem, currently.

Comment: @aryodgh It was [private-data-public-channel-2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1141471/private-data-public-channel-2), who edited. I just complained ;) ...

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2: If I want to restate the problem I should say: I have around 300 real numbers. They are the angels of 300 lines. I want to know the dominant angle w.r.t number of repetitions. If they where integer numbers, I could find the histogram of repetition of numbers and the peak could give me the dominant angle. 
I can do some sort of quantization here also. But I think it is not a good idea. Maybe if I can create a pdf for these real valued numbers, then I can find the probability of any angle from the pdf.

Comment: I feel this might need more code to be on-topic on SO. Anyway, you can probably use some (1- or N-D) minimization library like the one from gsl to implement the solution.

Comment: maybe just calculate average and deviation, assume normal distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for a snippet of code in c++ for fitting a probability
>   distribution function to this vector.

If you want to fit a probability function to a given data, then you have two options.

### Parametric methods.

To describe a probability you have to calculate a parameters that describes this probability. This can be done with [method of moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)) or [maximum likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) method. Maximum likelihood is very flexible.

So usually we calculate estimation of mean and variance ( i.e. for normal distribution) from a given data and these parameters are enough to describe probability.

### Non - parametric methods.

Transformation of cumulative distribution function is being fitted to data ( which may also need to be transformed).

[examples](http://myfitter.hepforge.org/)

Comment: Mean and variance are the parameters for Gaussian distributions, but not for many other things (exponential, Poisson, Chi-squared, etc.)

Comment: That is why I said "usually"

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2, thanks very much for your reply. I think that's what I am looking for. The non-parametric methods more suit my problem. I need to do [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). I am looking for a light-weighted library or implementation of that.

After estimating the kernel, how can I find the [Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) of distribution?

Comment: Mode is most frequent value in a data set, do you need further assistance?